# Is it safe to pass a cursor to another activity?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cursor

I'm trying to do horizontal swiping using a cursor but I'm just not grokking something, and hopefully someone here can help me understand.

I've got an activity that shows a list of items. It uses a `ListView` that is backed by a custom `CursorAdapter`, and that adapter is managed by a `LoaderCallback`. This is all standard stuff.

When the user clicks an item in the list, I want to show detailed information about that item. Currently I start a new activity, passing the ID of the selected item. This activity would load information about the item from a database. Again, standard stuff.

Now, going back and forth between the list of items and clicking an item to show more detail about that item is not the best user experience, and it would be preferable to allow the user to click an item to display its information, then allow swiping to show detail about the next or previous item in the list.

So I assume that when an item is clicked in the `ListView`, I need to start an activity that contains a `ViewPager`. This `ViewPager` is backed by a PagerAdapter that is responsible for fetching views at the appropriate position.

So I'd like to pass the `CursorAdapter` used in the list activity to the detail activity, and then implement a `PagerAdapter` that traverses the cursor to show the detail for the current item in the view pager. This seems simple enough: `getItem(pos)` would call `cursor.moveToPosition(pos)` then create a Fragment from the cursor, etc.

But (1) I'm not sure how to pass a `CursorAdapter` to an activity, as I don't think it can be serialized for passing within a bundle and (2) I'm hesitant to pass a CursorAdapter to another activity anyway because there's no `LoaderCallbacks` attached to manage the lifecycle.

One possible solution is to start the new activity and have that activity perform a new search to get an equivalent cursor to the cursor found in the list activity. For example, the list activity may have shown the items matching "title=foo", so when item 10 is clicked we create a new detail activity that shows information about item 10, but also performs a "title=foo" search to obtain a cursor that can be used in horizontal swiping. But that means I'm performing the same search twice: once in the list view, and once in the paging view. This may be an issue if the search takes some time.

I could also store the cursor in some global static area (such as `Application`) but that seems fraught with peril as well.

There's also `Parcelable` but I assume this means that I am serializing the cursor on one side and deserializing it on the other side. For large lists it may be more efficient to just perform the search again to get a new cursor.

I'm sure this is a common scenario, so I'd like to know what is best practice for managing cursors across multiple activities, or if some other approach may be better.

Comment: Can't you create a database to back your list items and pass the index to the informational activity? Or create a hidden view on top of your list view to display the information for the selected item and hide it when the user wants to go back to the list view.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am intrigued by your suggestion of creating a detail view on top of the existing list view in the existing activity. Instead of using a separate activity at all. I assume here one would  remove the list view from the layout in the `onListItemClicked` handler, and then add the `ViewPager` to the layout. Tricky issues would be handling the back button to return to the original list view, and what to do in landscape mode, when the detail view would exist alongside the list view (using fragments). But I will give this some more thought.

Comment: Also I am using a database; if using a separate detail activity one option (that I already suggested) is to perform the same search again and than call `cursor.moveToPosition()` based on the position of the list item. I'm not fond of this option because it means performing the same search twice with associated performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. please don't be passing any cursor or cursor adapters or anything like that to other activities. At some level of the process, you must have had to pass the activity's `context` for an object's creation. If that object somehow made into another activity using another's context, things'd probably go bonkers.

Moreover i don't see why you need the adapter itself in the first place. Isn't there a way that you could use just the cursor (re-instantiate) the same cursor for your new activity, pass the position clicked in and make your `PagerAdapter` and then pre-select the detail position that you want to view? just like what you said but you dont need a new search, pass the `position` in the intent.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I kinda thought that passing cursors between activities would be a bad idea, which is why I was loathe to do it and to seek suggestions. I think what you are suggesting here is to generate a new cursor in the new activity, then move that cursor according to the position of the clicked list item? But I'm not sure how to create a new cursor in a new activity without performing another search.

Comment: well yes you have to perform a query. But a query isn't going to be the most resource intensive step that you'd take. you make the query just to load your `pageAdapter` then move the *pageAdapter* according the position of the clicked item.

Comment: So I have opted to generate a new query in the new activity. It annoys me to perform the same search twice, but I see no other safe way.

Comment: If it's that much a bother, you could try to put both components in the same activity but perhaps in a viewswitcher so it appears different.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the `ViewSwitcher` class. Switching between two views was mentioned in an earlier comment, but I may give it a go now that I know about this class. My current implementation has an activity showing a list view, when then starts another activity to show the paging view. But a `ViewSwitcher` may be a better solution: switch from list view to pager view when an item is clicked in the list view, and switch from pager view to list view when back button is pressed (assuming that can be handled).